# Connect existing Django server project and to local host

Tags: python, django, mysql-python

I have a django project that have been maintaining on the cpanel server over 3years now with close to 30k lines of code, now I want to work with it on local machine for maintainance but after downloading codes and migrating new database, there are about thousands of database variable that reply on populated database field and will take me months to figure all out.. Anyway I can make a mini copy of my server mysql database and connect or is there any Starndard way to resolve this issue??

Comment: We can't really help without more details and I am assuming with more details this would begin to lack focus. If you don't have any seed data to populate the database initially and you application depends on those, you'll have to create the seed data.

Comment: You can take dump of your prod database and restore it into local system.

Comment: @AjayK am using MySQL in production how can I export part of it and still be able to reuse locally

Comment: how big your db is?